# Possible Ways to Style a View (Block)

Tags: 7, views, blocks

What are the possible ways one can style a View (Block) in Drupal 7? I have a View outputting to a Block on a Drupal 7 site that has custom styles which I need to copy; however, I cant seem to find where they are located.

Answer (score 1):

The possible ways are:

1) using a CSS file, ex: **style.css** (located in your `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/css` folder)

```
.block { border: solid red; }
```

2) using jQuery, ex: **style.js** (located in your `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/js` folder)

```
$('.block').css({"border":"solid red"});
```

3) using a template file, ex: **block.tpl.php** or **view.tpl.php** (located in your theme's `/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/template` folder)

```
<style>
.block { border: solid red; }
</style>
```

4) **Inside the view**, if they add a **header or footer** of `text area` or `unfiltered text` and then put inside the header/footer:

```
<style>
.block { border: solid red; }
</style>
```

or

```
<script src="myScript.js"></script>
```

5) Using the [CSS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/css_injector) module

6) Using the [JS Injector](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_injector) module

Comment: Are there any ways that are located within the Block or View editing screens?

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes, they could've added a header or a footer that contains the css.

Comment: @MadPhysicist if you provide me a link to your view, I am sure I can quickly pin point were it is coming from.

Comment: As in the page with the view? Does it matter if the view in question is done as a Block?

Comment: @MadPhysicist well actually the page that contains the block.

Comment: Can I PM you somehow?

Comment: I was able to resolve it. Looks like it had to do with the way the Block was formatted (Table, List, etc) rather than styling directly. Thanks for the help!